# right side overflow on page

Tags: html, css

I have some issue with this page I'm working on, I guess I've been staring to long at this to see the problem.. The right side has gotten a extra space somehow and I'm going bold trying to get rid of it..
any help would be highly appreciated.

[enter link description here](http://33tpm.com/accente/)

Comment: if you want to create a fluid layout then why your left extra space from sides?or if you want center content this is not correct way.you must set a fixed with for content-wrapper and then center it.

Answer (score 0):

Because your are giving margin to content-wrapper

```
<div id="content-wrapper"> while also providing width :100% of container
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems your content-wrapper's width is not necessary. You set it to 100% (which is the default) but this will be added to the padding/margin. Either remove the width or the padding/margin and it should work, I think. And of course remove the margin! (works for me in chrome, at least)

Answer (score 0):

content_wrapper has `width: 100%,` but there is also `margin-right 8%,` so real width is 108%. Read about model box and how it works with margins and paddings.

Answer (score 0):

your element .content-wrapper has 100% width and additional margin-left and right and than it will be longer than the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the input, I ended up deleting the "content-wrapper" And for centering the liquid divs I added a left margin on the left [column] divs and a right margin on the right [column] divs.